# Check if an Enum object is sequentially after another Enum object?

Tags: java, enums, bukkit

I have an enumeration, and when I choose a specific one (Example: `Rank.MOD`) I want to enable a specific permission to the other enums above the `MOD`.

For example, a Bukkit command requires `Rank.MOD`. If the player is `Rank.ADMIN`, I need to allow the execution of this command as well.

```
public enum Rank {
    STARTER("Starter", 0, false),
    PRODUCER("Producer", 20000, false),
    DEALER("Dealer", 50000, false),
    SMUGGLER("Smuggler", 100000, false),
    POLICE("Police", 0, false),
    MOD("Mod", 0, true),
    ADMIN("Admin", 0, true),
    OWNER("Owner", 0, true);

    private String rankName;
    private int rankCost;
    private boolean staff;

    Rank(String rankName, int rankCost, boolean staff) {
        this.rankName = rankName;
        this.staff = staff;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.rankName;
    }

    public int getCost() {
        return this.rankCost;
    }

    public boolean isStaff() {
        return this.staff;
    }
}
```

And here is where I check for the rank.

```
if ( !PlayerData.get().getRank(this.cmdSender).equals(this.rank.getName())) {
    cmdSender.sendMessage(F.parse("Permission", "You need the " +
        C.rank("[" + this.rank.getName()+ "]") +
        " rank to execute this command."));
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your question correctly - you want a way to do "this rank or above" check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ordinal()` method of Enum class that will return the index in enumeration array so for example:

```
Rank.ADMIN.ordinal() < Rank.OWNER.ordinal() // true
```

this way you can check based on permission required and someone's rank if he's allowed to do whatever he wants to do. That will work assuming that you sorted your ranks in your enum implementation from the least privileged to the most privileged.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options:

- You can add to each rank a list or ranks that it is allowed to act as, and check whether the rank needed is in the list of the rank you have.
- Create separate permissions enum and use those in security checks (similar to the one above)
- Add a "security level" number to rank, and check whether the rank number your rank has is above the required rank number

Lucass idea is interesting, but doesn't allow for more complex hierarchies than single trunk